# How can I enable SSO between two Cloud Applications running on two different Azure tenants?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2b

I have application A running on Azure Cloud A hosted on tenant A. This users defined in AAD.

I have another application B running on Azure Cloud B hosted on tenant B.

How can I enable SSO between Application A and Application B ?

Answer (score 0):

B2B or multi-tenant app support depending on who is responsible for authorizing users to access the apps. If only owners of tenant A can authorize users to access app A then you need to B2B invite users from tenant B to A. If owners of B should be the ones to determine which of their users should be authorized then implement app A as a [multi-tenant app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/setup-multi-tenant-app). Same question applies to app B.